# Drain Fly Infestation

Tags: bathroom, pest-control, insect

After having a bathroom toilet drain clog cleared by a plumber by using a snake, we have experienced an infestation of drain moths. How may we eliminate the infestation?

Comment: Hello Machavity. Thank you for answering my question. I know what you mean when asking whether I've determined  where they reside. The answer is no, but I'm trying.

Comment: I placed adhesive tape over the drain in the kitchen sink, and the bathroom sink and tub drains overnight. The tape, when lifted in the morning, showed no flies. I'm thinking that I should have used clear tape to allow light to attract the drain flies. I've also cleaned the pipes with a two foot long brush, and applied a product called "Drain Gel afterwards. By the way, I spoke of the removal and replacement of our toilet by a plumber to clear a clog 10 feet into the sewer line caused by flushed baby wipes. The plumber did not place a rag into the sewer line and did not caulk the toilet base.

Comment: We reside in a condominium complex with an on-property waste water treatment facility. Have you or others observed drain flies entering a condominium through the pipe connected to the waste water treatment facility, and through the uncaulked space between the base of the toilet and the floor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are saying a product like invade bio drain will work https://www.doyourownpestcontrol.com/drainflies.htm

If by drain flies you mean fruit flies I've had flawless success with a shallow bowl of apple cider vinegar with a little Dawn on top.  They fly in and can't get out.  A few days to clear em out.